# The output of the counter to this multi-threaded code

Tags: java, multithreading

I came across a Java problem about multi-threaded programming (please see the code below). Based on [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6498982/multithread-state-dependent-issue) and answer on StackOverflow, I think I understand why there could be a deadlock. But what I don't understand was if the program works correctly (i.e. there is no deadlock), what would be the value of `foo` printed? I thought it would be 20 (thread1 counting up to 10 and thread2 counting up to 10 more). Could someone help me explain how this might (preferably in a simple way because I'm still new to thread programming)? Thank you.

```
public class ThreadTest{

  private static class ThreadOne extends Thread{
    private ThreadTwo threadTwo; 
    public int foo = 0;

    public void setThreadTwo(ThreadTwo th){
       threadTwo = th;
    }

    public void run(){
      try{
        for(int i=0;i<10;i++) foo += i;

        synchronized(this){this.notify();};

        synchronized(threadTwo){threadTwo.wait();};

        System.out.print("Foo: " + threadTwo.foo);
      }catch(InterruptedException e){ e.printStackTrace();}    
    }
  }

  private static class ThreadTwo extends Thread{

    private final ThreadOne threadOne;
    public int foo = 0;

    public ThreadTwo(ThreadOne th){
      threadOne = th;
    }

    public void Run(){
       try{
         synchronized(threadOne){threadOne.wait();}
         foo = threadOne.foo;

         for(int i=0;i<10;i++) foo += i;
         synchronized(this){this.notify();};
           }
       catch(InterruptedException e){e.printStackTrace();}    
    }    
  }

  public static void main(){
    ThreadOne th1 = new ThreadOne();
    ThreadTwo th2 = new ThreadTwo(th1);

    th1.setThreadTwo(th2);

    th1.start(); th2.start();
    th1.join(); th2.join();
  } 
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

According to your code and without deadlocks `foo` value will be 90 (if i didn't miscalculate). Because instead of `foo += 1` you did `foo += i`.

EDIT: Okay, step by step.

1. `foo` = 0
2. `th1` and `th2` starts. `th2` waits for notify. `th1` increments `foo` up to 45
3. `th1` notifies and starts to wait `th2`. `th2` is notified and starts to increment `foo` from 45 to 90
4. `th2` notifies `th1`. `th1` is notified, and it prints `th2.foo`, which is 90

EDIT 2: Correct way to count from 0 to 90 from 2 threads without concurrent modification is something like this

```
public class ThreadTest {
    private static int counter = 0;

    private static class Thread1 extends Thread {
        final Object lock;

        public Thread1(Object lock) {
            this.lock = lock;
        }

        @Override
        public void run() {
            synchronized (lock) {
                for (int i = 0; i < 10; i++)
                    counter += i;
            }
        }
    }

    private static class Thread2 extends Thread {
        final Object lock;

        public Thread2(Object lock) {
            this.lock = lock;
        }

        @Override
        public void run() {
            synchronized (lock) {
                for (int i = 0; i < 10; i++)
                    counter += i;
            }
        }
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        final Object lock = new Object();

        final Thread th1 = new Thread1(lock);
        final Thread th2 = new Thread2(lock);

        th1.start();
        th2.start();

        try {
            th1.join();
            th2.join();
        } catch (InterruptedException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }

        System.out.println("Counter: " + counter);
    }
}
```

But if you are forced to use `wait` and `notify`, than it's a bit more complicated. Use object of this class as common lock instead of Object

```
class Locker {

        private boolean isLocked = false;

        public synchronized void lock() throws InterruptedException {
            while (isLocked) wait();
            isLocked = true;
        }

        public synchronized void unlock() {
            isLocked = false;
            notify();
        }
    }
```

And in `run` method us it like this:

```
@Override
public void run() {
    try {
        locker.lock();
        for (int i = 0; i < 10; i++)
            counter += i;
        locker.unlock();
    } catch (InterruptedException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
}
```

Comment: Thank you. So you're suggesting that (without deadlocks) every time threadOne gets a chance to do one iteration (i.e. foo += i), threadTwo will get a chance to add 10 times? Could you expand on your answer (e.g., step by step event of what goes on for the first few steps without deadlocks) a little bit so that a beginner like me can understand this?

Comment: And what output do you get?

Comment: Ah, thank you! It was my mistake. I failed to see that 1+2+3+...+9 = 45. The code above doesn't output anything when I compile (successfully) and run on my machine. If you have a suggestion as to how to fix this to work, could you please share? This is very helpful, btw. I'm going to accept your answer above. :)

Comment: I'm not quite sure what are you intending to do :) Do you want 2 threads to increment same variable concurrently? Or one by one (but why do you need 2 threads then)? Is it required to use `wait()` and `notify()` methods?

Comment: I'm not sure what this code is trying to accomplish either (because I saw it on a Java multithread puzzle). :) I assume it is testing if the candidate can figure out a way to fix the deadlock and still get 90 as the final answer. Assuming this is true, is there a proper way to fix the deadlock (without removing a thread; that is, keep using two threads to count up to 90)? Thank you again!

Comment: Regarding if it's required to use `wait()` and `notify()`: yes, if possible. I'd like to learn how one might solve this deadlock without changing the core structure (method calls, etc.) of the program. If there is a more elegant way to fix it, I'd also like to learn that as well. Sorry about asking too much and thank you so much for the answers. :)

Comment: And frankly I can't believe such puzzles are given in the interview. It's awful. I would advise you to read some concurrency tutorials, like [this](http://tutorials.jenkov.com/java-concurrency/index.html). There is great tutorial with tons of examples and explanations

Comment: Yeah, I agree. I changed some variable names and formatting because the original code was a bit difficult to read. Coincidentally, I stumbled upon the site you suggested yesterday. Still haven't finished reading it, but hope to do so today. Thank you again for your help! :) I'll post the answer back if I figure out how to make `notify()` and `wait()` works.

Edit: I didn't realize you already wrote out the solution above. But I'm not going to look at it until I solve it myself! Thank you so much!!